# Boolean parameter validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apipie

I have a parameter defined as such:

```
param :purchased, [true, false]
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Invalid parameter 'purchased' value true: Must be one of: true, false.
```

I have also tried:

```
param :purchased, [true, false, 'true', 'false']
```

but it didn't change anything.

Unfortunately also I cannot cover this in the tests as there the sent boolean is always cast into a String. Then the error looks like this:

```
Invalid parameter 'purchased' value "true": Must be one of: true, false.
```

Can anybody help here? Also I would be happy to just disable the validation of Apiepie as I am only interested in the documentation part.

Comment: Can you specifiy in which context `param :purchased, [true, false]` was defined

Comment: What do you mean with context exactly?
This is the entire apipie block. Does that help

```api :POST, '/memberships/', '...'
  param :course_id, String, :desc => "...", :required => true
  param :affiliate_id, :number, :desc => "The ID of the affiliate", :required => true
  param :purchased, [true, false, 'true', 'false'], :desc => "..."

  returns :code => 201 do
    property :membership, Membership, :desc => "When resource created."
  end
  returns :code => 200 do
    property :membership, Membership, :desc => "When resource existed."
  end
```

Comment: actually looking at my original post I see that due to formatting here, some info was strupped out the actual message says: "Invalid parameter 'purchased' value true: Must be one of: <code>true</code>, <code>false</code>."

Comment: so is "param" supposed to be hash of key value pairs?